# Including .js but failed to load resource

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a html file that includes several .js libraries from open sources Projects for example:

```
<script src=“js/three.min.js"></script>
```

But it says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

When I clicked on it, it says The requested URL /blabla/js/three.min.js was not found on this server. The .js files are in the folder called js which is stored in the same place as the html file. I've already gone through tons of Google search but couldn't find a way to solve it. Maybe it's a dumb question as I'm new to JavaScript. Can anybody kindly inform me what is the problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give us some code

Comment: If JS folder is in the same folder as html - then it's enough to reference by using relative path to JS files, such as:  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js" />

Comment: it could be that the two different types of double quotes that you use in your sample are not on good terms with each other ;). Try: <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your code? In meantime, you can have reference from below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.your_external_domain/blabla/js/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response. I used something like this: <script src=“js/three.min.js"></script> and I also tried to use the absolute path. But since I'm running it on the school server (https://) which requires username and password. Is it something to do with this?

Comment: Can you bring more details to authentication required? That may be the cause of getting HTTP 404 ..

Comment: @AbbyWanyuLiu if you use absolute path it never make issue. However if you like to use the relative issue, make sure you can when you view the source code of the page (do CTRL+U) and click on the referenced JS source link, you should be able to see the JS file's source code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file local or online ?

If online try to call http://www.your_external_domain/blabla/js/three.min.js with your browser.
If you can receive the file with your browser, your html should be although able to do it.
If not, maybe you cannot receive this file from your school server.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is answering saying he has to add `type="text/javascript"` as well.. but this isn't necessary anymore. If script tags do not contain the `type` property, it's Javascript automatically.

I read you're on your school server, so that might be it.. (the directory might require to read your username and password).

Try uploading the file somewhere (maybe here: http://yourjavascript.com/) and referring it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Try `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/three.min.js"></script>` (added a `/` in front of `js`).